# Is there any difference between these two cases: passing class name vs object

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and not sure about many idioms. I have found code where a function gets a class name as argument. Is there any reason to do it? I've simplified the code to this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print ("A")


def foo_1(a):
    inst = a()
    return inst


def foo_2(a):
    inst = a
    return inst


if __name__ == "__main__":
    i1 = foo_1(A)
    i2 = foo_2(A())
```

Is there any difference between implementing it like foo_1 ( the way it is implemented now), and the foo_2 (The way I would consider to be more intuitive)

Thanks!

Comment: foo_2 does nothing but return its argument? Did you simplify too much?
`i3 = A()`  would be the pythonic way for this example.

Comment: foo_1 receives a class, not a name. Classes are first class objects, like any other value.

Comment: For what you show, both are valid. Whether you pass a class to instantiate or a pre-instantiated object depends entirely on what you *need* to do.

Comment: @chepner I have to document the code and have no idea, which intentions the original developer had. Now I suspect, I could refactor foo_1 way to foo_2. Seems to be odd code.

Comment: @Demi-Lune Thank you! The sense of code is maintained in the example. Now I know, it can be refactored, there is no good reason behind the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These do slightly different things.

`foo_1` gets passed a `class` (itself an object), not just its name. It then instantiates an instance of that class, which it returns.

`foo_2` gets passed an instance (actually in this simplified example any object) and just returns it.

In this example this will mean that `i1` and `i2` seem to be the same. But they are actually different objects and will, for example, not compare equal.

You would use something like `foo_1` as a factory of instances of some class or to modify the class object before creating an instance. And you would use `foo_2` if you want to do something with an instance. In particular this means that if you call the function multiple times, you can pass the same instance every time, whereas `foo_1` will always generate a new instance.

So, it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: "to modify the class object before creating an instance" - cool!

Answer (score 1):

What you have as `foo_2` can be simplified as just using the object, which is what you should do.

Both options work, but `foo_1` is an odd way of doing things unless you don't have immediate access to the class you want to instantiate.

```
i = foo_2(A())
```

is the same as

```
i = A()
```

---

Say you had a new class `B`, which had to be instantiated with some paramters. It's more complicated to call that from `foo_1`.

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.c = c
```

You can do:

```
i = B()
j = foo_2(B())
k = foo_1(B) => TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'
```

You could modify `foo_1` to take paramters though, and that could be useful, if you didn't know what class you  might be instantiating (if you get the class via user input).

```
# function that takes 1 parameter followed by any number of paramters
def foo_3(klass, *params):
    inst = klass(*params)  # pass the any number of paramters onto the instantiation
    return inst
```

Comment: "foo_1 is an odd way of doing things" I've suspected it too, thank you!

Comment: It looks odd in this simplified example. There are perfectly valid reasons for writing a function like `foo_1` (`collections.defaultdict` is a prime example.)

Comment: Sure, this is just an example of when you might not want want to use something like `foo_1`.